# Chiddushei ha-Rim on the stork

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, kashrut-kosher, parashat-shemini, birds, parashat-reeh

In a d'var Torah on Parashat R'eh, Rabbi Mirvis [wrote](https://chiefrabbi.org/all-media/dvar-torah-parashat-reeh-5/):

> The Chidushei Harim … tells us that the ‘chasida’, the stork, is
> indeed selfless and kind-hearted, however, only to birds of its own
> feather. Towards other birds and other creatures, it acts with cruelty
> and distain. As a result it is not kosher.

I've found the relevant passage [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21531&pgnum=175) (although in relation to Parashat Sh'mini, not Parashat R'eh).

But Rabbi Mirvis adds, my emphasis:

> The Chiddushei Harim **goes on to tell us** that the laws of kashrut in
> our parashah do not only relate to what we can and can’t eat, but they
> tell us about us, ourselves. We shouldn’t lead a stork-like existence.
> In the event that our compassion and selflessness extends only to
> those within our own limited social clique, those within our own echo
> chamber, then ultimately, that is a ‘treif’ form of existence.

I can't find any such passage anywhere in Chiddushei ha-Rim. Can anyone help?

Many thanks.